# Using @Inject annotation causes var to be recognized as a @Test?

Tags: scala, testing, intellij-idea, dependency-injection, testng

```
@Test
class MyTestClass {

  @Inject
  var myInjectedVar: MyController = _

  @Test
  def myTest = { ... }
}
```

When I use IntelliJ, javax, and TestNG to run all tests in `MyTestClass`, `myTest` gets run as I would expect, but my output also shows an additional test that doesn't get run properly:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: 
Method myInjectedVar_$eq requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Test annotation.
```

Somehow, the `@Inject` annotation above appears to be creating a method named `myInjectedVar_$eq`, and then TestNG is expecting to be able to run it as if it had been annotated with `@Test`.

How do I inject `myInjectedVar` properly without TestNG expecting it to be a test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the @Test annotation from your class:

```
class MyTestClass {
    @Inject
    var myInjectedVar: MyController = _

    @Test
    def myTest = { ... }
}
```

see testng documentation for details: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#class-level

> The effect of a class level @Test annotation is to make all the public methods of this class to become test methods even if they are not annotated. You can still repeat the @Test annotation on a method if you want to add certain attributes.

the methods `myInjectedVar_=(v: MyController): Unit` and `myInjectedVar(): MyController` are methods generated by the scala compiler. Scala uses these methods to access the var.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you really prefer field injection, make it `private` or `private[this]`.

```
@Test
class X {

  @Inject
  private var myInjectedVar: MyController = _

  def myTest(): Unit = ???
}
```

It would be strange to give your testing class X a companion, but if you did so, you risk introducing synthetics and access widenings that would also confuse testng.